# Laravel insert random password in database when submitting form without password input

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to insert random password in database when I submit a form without password input field.

my model User.php

```
protected $fillable = [
    'email', 'firstname', 'lastname'
];

public function setpasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value ?: str_random(10));
}
```

my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    User::create(Request::all());
    return 'test';
}
```

my database

```
id
firstname
lastname
password
created_at
updated_at
```

my error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'password' doesn't have a default value 
(SQL: insert into `users` (`email`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
```

Comment: Maybe you can mark the password as optional? Like `$value = null` in the method

Comment: Or the field in the database is set as "Not-null" so you HAVE to provide a value when inserting.  Insert something or change the table definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'password' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`email`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)

You are getting this error because the default `create_users_table` migration doesn't provide default value to the `password` field or allow null as value.

when you call

```
User::create($request->all());
```

laravel perform an insert query to the database and because the `password` is not set, MySQL will return the `SQLSTATE[HY000]

You can solve that by modifying the `create_users_table` migration which came by default with a new created laravel project,

```
  Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // other table columns goes here
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        // OR 
        $table->string('password')->default("");
        // other table columns goes here
  });
```

this will allow you to create new User without provide a password and that column will be set to "" or left empty depending with the method you use to modify the migration like I suggest

Secondly defyning the `setPasswordAttribute` on your model doesn't means when you create a new user without password it will set automaticaly a password on that, you can do that by catching the `creating` event before inserting the user in the database.

to do that add this in you `EventServiceProvider`

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
    * Register any events for your application.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        User::creating(function($user){
            if($user->password === "" || empty($user->password)){
                $user->password  = bcrypt(str_random(10));;
            }
        })

    }
}
```

this event is trigger before the user is persiste in the database, and that will allow you to make some modification on all attributes that are allready set on the user you want to persiste in the database

Comment: Thank you it is exactly what I want when I enter email, firstname and lastname in a form automaticall insert info in database and insert a random password automatically generate too.

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to check as the answer to you question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is  at your controller: the `User::create(Request::all());` has not a password parameter and the mysql gives the correct error: `'password' doesn't have a default value`.

This is something you can do about it:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = Request::all();
    $input[password] = $input[password] ? $input[password] : bcrypt(str_random(10))
    User::create(Request::all());
    return 'test';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for password input in your request and if it doesn't exist, just fake it:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if (!$request->has('password')) {
        $password = str_random(8);
        $request->request->add(['password' => bcrypt($password)]);
    }
    User::create($request->all());
    return 'test';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method name should be `setPasswordAttribute` not `setpasswordAttribute`.